# Double slit experiment confusions

Tags: visible-light, double-slit-experiment

In the past I have read about the double slit experiment and I just barely understood it and I am wondering if someone could put it in simpler terms and explain the results and what they mean.

Comment: It is difficult to answer you because you have not explained what it is about the double slit experiment that you do not understand.

Comment: Specify more about which point is not clear to you.

Answer (score 2):

A double slit experiment is a way of illustrating one of the properties of waves, called interference.

When waves overlap, then depending on a number of factors their respective peaks and troughs might align with each other (that is known as constructive interference) or cancel each other out (which is known as destructive interference). This is probably easiest to visualise with water waves, but the principle is a very general one which applies to all kinds of waves.

Perfect alignment or misalignment of peaks and troughs rarely occurs naturally, since waves are usually created by processes that have some degree of randomness associated with them, so usually we do not see perfectly destructive or constructive interference, as those effects are swamped by all the intermediate cases where waves arrive in some intermediate state and the effects tend to cancel out.

A two slits experiment is a way to make interference stand-out more clearly. Essentially an incoming wave is split into two by passing it through a pair of slits so that immediately beyond the slits the peaks and troughs of the two parts are perfectly aligned with each other. The two parts of the wave spread out (as waves tend to do) until they hit a screen. At the screen, the part of the wave from one slit overlaps with the part from the other slit, and depending on the exact spacing of the slits and the screen, and upon their wavelength, the alignment of the peaks and troughs of the two parts will vary along the screen on account of the fact that each has travelled a slightly different distance to arrive there. Where the waves arrive perfectly aligned you see a bright spot. Where they are perfectly misaligned you see nothing because they have cancelled out. There are countless demonstrations of this on the internet if you look for them.

The experiment has been used to demonstrate that what we previously thought of as particles, such as electrons, also have wave-like properties, as when you fire electrons through slits they exhibit interference patterns just as any other wave would.

What makes the two slits experiment particularly difficult to understand in quantum mechanics is that the interference pattern emerges even if you fire the electrons through the slits one at a time, so somehow the wavelike aspect of the electron is passing through both slits and interfering with itself. That goes against our intuition that the electron, being a particle, should pass through either one slit or the other. (Before you ask, physicists have taken all the obvious steps to check this, by closing one of the slits to see what happens etc etc).

So we are left with the conundrum that electrons (and other particles) have some spread-out wavelike characteristic associated with them which makes them exhibit interference, and yet in other respects they seem to behave in a particle-like fashion (ie as if they have a very small spatial extent). This is known as the 'wave-particle' duality. It was encountered about a century ago and remains a problem of interpretation for quantum mechanics, which is the branch of physics that models how matter and energy interact at a small scale.

Answer (score 0):

The double-slit experiment shows how quantum particles in some conditions behave like a wave. It was done first with photons by G. I. Taylor (1909) and has been done many times since then with other particles.

The **setup** consists of a beam of particles, a double-slit and a detector.

First, if you use a beam of light (that is, a wave) what you have in the detector is an interference pattern. This is the **Young's experiment**, that shows the wave properties of light. Take a look at [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Iuv6hY6zsd0) explaining this experiment.

The **double-slit experiment** has a modification: the intensity of the beam (made by one kind of quantum particle) is so low that only one photon at a time passes by the slit. What you observe in the detector is again an interference pattern. That means that the particle is passing the slit behaving as a wave.

**This experiment confirms the wave-particle duality introduced by Louis de Broglie: quantum particles behave as particles OR as waves.**